# Use OS in the flash card with VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, armbian

I'm not sure if it's possible or even if it is how practical would it be but this thought just popped up in my head as I was trying to set up my Armbian Ubuntu 18.04 for my Orange Pi PC.

I have flashed the OS on a memory card and it boots perfectly. I was wondering that instead of booting the OS on my Orange Pi, is it possible for me to boot it on a VirtualBox?

Theoretically, the flash card is simply a disk with a bootable OS on it so I should be able to connect it somewhere under storage option of the VirtualBox and it should work, right? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest flaw in your reasoning is that you do not seem to understand the difference between the Orange Pi and the Virtualbox/PC you are using.

Whilst theoretically, with the use of command line, VirtualBox can be instructed to boot from media instead of VM files, the real question here is that your notebook and VirtualBox only run and recognize the x86 architecture and your Orange Pi PC run and has binaries of a different architecture.

The architecture of the Orange Pi PC is Arm, which has a different way of working, different binaries, different memory layout and different opcodes.

In the end, it would be as asking someone that only knows English to read and speak Russian.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out once I started digging deeper. My concept was flawed. Now I'm trying to find a way to emulate the ARM Architecture using `qemu`. Let's hope it works.